# Return variable set in jinja2 to python scripts

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

I'm working with Flask and Jinja2. In the main scripts (in python) I call a template. In this template, the user can select different options and I save this option in a variable. My problem is, How I return the variable to my main script??

This in my template code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
  {%- for i in range(cant) %}
  <tr class={{ "success" if i.done }}>
<td>
    <label>Sensor Nº {{ i }}:</label>
    <select name="name" {{ i }} width="400px">
      <option value="1">-- Selecionar --</option>
      <option value="2">TMP101 1</option>
      <option value="3">TMP101 2</option>
      <option value="4">Presión</option>
      <option value="5">Humedad</option>
      <option value="6">Carga</option>
    </select>
</td>

{% set var = name %}
{{ var }}
  {%- endfor %}
</table>
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't specify how you wan't to return it to script ? It can be done as a form submit (form with hidden field).

Comment: I need return the select value (1, 2, 3, .. or 6) How is work form submit ??

Comment: The form submit will be a part of the Flask view function. First, you will need the form in the template to submit a `POST` request. This request will go to a Flask view (usually the same on you are already on). So in the Flask view, you want to check if it is a `POST` request or not, then act accordingly.